# useRouter does not push inside other composables

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, nuxtjs3

I am creating a basic login screen with Nuxt.js3. I have a `useFirebaseAuth()` composable function that uses the Firebase Auth to sign in and sign out the user. Here is my code below:

```js
import { signInWithEmailLink, signOut } from "@firebase/auth"

export default function() {
  const { $auth } = useNuxtApp() // retrieved from plugin

  const verifyEmailLinkSignIn = async () => {
    ...
    const result = await signInWithEmailLink($auth, email, window.location.href)
    if (result) {
      useRouter().push("/home") // <- DOES NOT PUSH TO HOME
    }
  }

  const signOutUser = async () => {
    await signOut($auth)
    useRouter().push("/login") // <- DOES NOT PUSH TO LOGIN
  }

  return {
    ...,
    verifyEmailLinkSignIn,
    signOutUser
  }
}
```

When the user has successfully used the link in the email to sign in, they should be automatically redirected to the home page. However, they need to refresh the page to do so (I have redirects enabled in both pages, so it works on refresh). How do I automatically redirect them to the required page?

Comment: is there any error in console ? Just some thoughts : you are not importing `useRouter`, what does `console.log(useRouter())` returns ?

Comment: In Nuxt3, useRouter() is auto-imported. The console shows the Router object when I am printing it.

Comment: Not sure but you can try putting `useRouter()` outside the function. Use it like the way you use `useNuxtApp`